# Javascript: http request connect timeout

Tags: javascript, http, google-search-console

Recently I have been dealing with some issues on my website in Search Console. It seems on multiple crawls my site returns a timeout, disabling Google from crawling the page. I've been trying to figure out what the cause is but then I remembered I had implemented some new javascript some time ago, that executes http requests to evaluate whether an image src is dead or not, and if so replaces it with a new src url.

e.g.

```
$(".productimage img").each( function() {
    var image_url2 = $(this).attr("src");
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("HEAD", image_url2, false);
    http.send();

    if(http.status == "404") {
      var newimage_url2 = "https://example.com/img/newimage.png";
      $(this).attr("src",newimage_url2)
    }
});
```

I was wondering whether such http requests could strain the server and be a possible cause of the connect timeout error?

Would love to hear your thoughts on and experiences with it.

Take care!

Answer (score 0):

In code above I see missed part - you cannot check status at once after sending request, you should wait for answer first

```
  $(".productimage img").each( function() {
  var image_url2 = $(this).attr("src");
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  http.open("HEAD", image_url2, false);
 http.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 404) {
        var newimage_url2 = "https://example.com/img/newimage.png";
  $(this).attr("src",newimage_url2)
    };
  };
 })
```

It is hard to say, how it can affect crawling, but let try and see

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your response. The code runs fine on the website (i.e. it does what its supposed to do). I just wondered if it demands a lot of computing given that it needs to check another site while opening mine. Any thoughts?